# How to edit other form's properties in c#?

Tags: c#

On Form1, I want to make a button wich switches on/off a Form2's label's visibility (visible true or false). Thank you much, I'm beginner!

Comment: Might be useful to give us more information... like how, why, what you have access to, what you tried and so on.

Comment: Also where you create and show Form2 will help

Comment: Make a public method in Form2 that switches visibility of the label. Then you need a reference to the Form2 in the Form1 and just call that method. The more advanced solution would involve invoking a delegate that does the same thing.

Comment: So on form 1 there is a button named "Form2 label on/off" and on the form 2 there is a label, which depending on the button is visible or not. Of course I have more difficult program but its same. It is also good if I make 2 buttons, one is off, one is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is what you should do. The simpler but not recommended solution. I have written it just to show how simple it can be:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
        Form2 form2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool labelVisible = form2.ToggleLabelVisibility();
        }
 }
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
     public Form2()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     public bool ToggleLabelVisibility()
     {
         label1.Visible = !label1.Visible;
         return label1.Visible;
     }
}
```

The better solution should Invoke delegate on the Form2:
In Form1 change only this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      bool labelVisible = (bool)form2.Invoke(form2.ToggleVisibility);
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate bool visibilityToggler();
    public visibilityToggler ToggleVisibility;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToggleVisibility = new visibilityToggler(ToggleLabelVisibility);
    }
    public bool ToggleLabelVisibility()
    {
        label1.Visible = !label1.Visible;
        return label1.Visible;
    }
}
```

I must say that this is old school, I am sure that there are many other ways to do this especially from C# 4.0 but this is how I did it for years.

Answer (score 1):

First, on Form2, change the label's `Modifiers` to `public`.

This code assumes that that there is only Form1 and Form2 open at the same time. The `Application.OpenForms[]` array contains the currently open forms, so you can access them from other form objects.

If you want one on-off button, then create a button click event handler, for example:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    Namespace.Form2 form2 = (Namespace.Form2)Application.OpenForms[1];

    //Single Button event handler    
    private void onOffClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           form2.LableName.Visible = !form2.LabelName.Visibility;
    }
}
```

Now, if you would like BOTH an on and an off button, then create an event handler for each button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Namespace.Form2 form2 = (Namespace.Form2)Application.OpenForms[1];

    //On Button event handler    
    private void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           form2.LableName.Visible = true; 
    }

    //off Button event handler    
    private void offClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           form2.LableName.Visible = false;
    }
}
```